# Geopoint, Geocoordinate, Geoposition or GeoCoordinate on Windows Store & Windows Phone apps?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I'm confused which I'm supposed to use?  I was using GeoCoordinate in Windows Phone 8, but that doesn't exist in Windows Store 8.1.  Then I was going to use Geoposition, but I saw Visual Studio underlined it and said it will not be supported later.

Which one should I use to maintain best compatibility between Windows Store and Windows Phone apps?

All I need is to work on the Latitude and Longitudes.

Answer (score 1):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66/sourcecode?fileId=43753&pathId=180041592

using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;  //is the key using necessary for this newer "merged runtime"

Link shows you source related to windows phone based on example from MS using the newer api, I believe there are only slight differences in the code for Win8.1 usage as well.

this all assumes Windows Phone 8.1 or Windows 8.1,  believe the Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 uses the older method still ( I could be wrong haven't updated any of my projects yet).